# How can I insert code into : <ul><li>here</li></ul> ..that will spawn a sized window.

Tags: javascript, html

cant get this to work (can I not have JS call from inside list tags?)
Thanks!!!

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
    function newPopup(url) {
 popupWindow = window.open(
 url,'popUpWindow','height=300,width=400,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="helpingkidswhostruggle.html" target="popup" onclick="window.open('helpingkidswhostruggle.html','name','width=600,height=450')">Helping Kids Who Struggle</a>
</li>
            
</ul>
```

```html
..etc

,,but works fine when not in <li>
Thanks!!!
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  What "isn't working" here?  Do you see errors in your console?  You can put on `onclick` on basically any element, so the fact that you are inside a `<li>` has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Why this second example ?

Comment: Ive tried image based pop up JS that worked within li tags but I need this to be a text link

Comment: Hello Lionel, Im finding that only a full size window is spawned, not a sized window. If I pull the html out of the li tag it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use the [jquery](https://jquery.com/) library for this solution. In order to use jquery you have to include the jquery files using a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) or locally. I use a CDN.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

You can set up a jquery event listener so that once a list item is clicked, an event is executed. For example;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>List Click</title>

<!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Include the jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="group">
    <li id="one">One</li>
    <li id="two">Two</li>
    <li id="three">Three</li>
    <li id="four">Four</li>
    <li id="five">Five</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $( "#group li" ).bind( "click", function() {
          var selected_item = $(this).attr('id');
            if(selected_item == "one"){
             window.open('helpingkidswhostruggle.html','name','width=600,height=450');
            }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So to explain the code;

You must assign id attributes to the `ul` and `li` tags.

The `$( "#group li" ).bind( "click", function() {` code looks for the list items with tags of `li` enclosed in an element with an id of `group` and assigns a click listener to them so that when they are clicked, a function is called and executed.

The `var selected_item = $(this).attr('id');` code uses the `attr('id')` method to obtain the id of the clicked list item and assign it to variable `selected_item`. So now this is the use of assigning an `id` to the list items so that you can identify them.

This `if(selected_item == "one"){` code of course checks to see which item has been clicked and the action to take if it has. You can play around with this and see what works for you.

Do not forget to include the jquery files otherwise the code will not work.

Try it and let me know if it helps or if you found a problem

Comment: Douglas, Thanks so much for your time. Ive tried your suggestion to no avail, but Im a begiiner so it's likely that Im not following directions correctly. Or maybe its related to that fact that Im using a 3rd party menu builder with its own css 

Ive posted what I though to be your direction at http://frcps.org/test/   btw, Im trying to spawn a different window from each link.

Comment: Hey Dan, i doubt if the css has a problem, it should work with it. Am going to edit my answer so that i can explain my example. Please take a look at it.